# How to ask to the user if project shutdown by using another WPF Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

This is MainWindow xaml codes.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Name="MainWindow" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="500">
</Window>
```

This is Window1 xaml codes.

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Name="Window1" 
Height="200" 
Width="500">

<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" Margin="10,20,10,0">
            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                <Run Name="Inline1" Text="Message"/>
            </TextBlock.Inlines>
        </TextBlock>

        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" LastChildFill="False">
            <Button Name="Button1" Content="No" Width="70" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
            <Button Name="Button2" Content="Yes" Width="70" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This is MainWindow vb codes.

```
Class MainWindow

Private Sub MainWindow_Closing(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    Dim myWindow As New Window1()
    myWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
    myWindow.Inline1.Text = "Do you really want to quit?"
    myWindow.ShowDialog()
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub

End Class
```

This is Window1 vb codes.

```
Public Class Window1

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

1- Run this project.

2- Click **X** in order to shutdown this project.

3- Click **Yes** button when the project asks you Do you really want to quit?

4- See following error;

https://prnt.sc/ih9l5f

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (correct me if I'm wrong) you want to recieve an input back fro the [Window1] which is kind of like a message box asking to shutdown? So i guess there is a couple of buttons [Yes]/[No] [Confirm]/[Dont Shutdown] which the user clicks on?

If so...
Declare a public boolean in Window1 Class and then BEFORE the close, or app shutdown set the boolean to true / false as you require.

```
Public Class Window1
Public Confirmed as boolean = false

'I have set to default as boolean as the user could theroretically close the
'form and not click on either button!?

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Confirmed = true
    ''System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown()
    me.close
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Confirmed = false
    Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class



Class MainWindow

Private Sub MainWindow_Closing(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    Dim myWindow As New Window1()
    ''myWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow ''I dont know why you need this?
    myWindow.Inline1.Text = "Do you really want to quit?"
    myWindow.ShowDialog()
    if mywindow.confirmed then
         System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown()
         ''or simply..
         ''application.exit()
    else
         e.Cancel = True
    end if

End Sub

End Class
```

This is not by any means the only way, please dont take this answer as completely correct as your stuation can be achieved lots of ways, one of which is the way you have done already. To be honest I can see why / how the error is occurring on the showdialog, but removing the window and handling back in the MainWindow would cut out an issues / errors with the Window1.

Hope this helps in some way
Chicken